# Automating multiple variable withdrawal from an object

Tags: r

Here's my situation. I have an object that I've created using `read.spss`.

```
> a <- read.spss(...)
> attach(a)
```

Now in this object `a` is a set questions that I would like to pull out that follows a sequence of question numbers:

```
> q3 <- data.frame(q3_1, q3_2, q3_4, ... q3_27)
```

Is there a way to automate it such that it pulls out all questions starting with `q3_` from the original object into the new `q3 data.frame`?

I've tried using the `paste` function to no avail.

```
> q3 <- data.frame(paste("q3_",1:27,sep=""))
```

That just returns a `data.frame` with the pasted sequence.

Ideally, I would like something that pulls in everything from a question beginning with a `qX_`, as some values are missing or outdated.

Answer (score 5):

Among the possibilities are `grep`, `match` and `%in%`. Here is a solution using `grep`:

```
R> foo <- data.frame(q1_1=1:4, q1_2=11:14, q2_1=21:24, q2_2=31:34, q3_1=41:44, q3_2=51:54)
R> colnames(foo)
[1] "q1_1" "q1_2" "q2_1" "q2_2" "q3_1" "q3_2"
R> grep("q3_", colnames(foo))
[1] 5 6
R> q3 <- foo[, grep("q3_", colnames(foo))]
R> q3
  q3_1 q3_2
1   41   51
2   42   52
3   43   53
4   44   54
R>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
q3 <- a[,grep("q3_",colnames(a))]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just do something like:

`q3 <- data.frame(a[paste('q3_',1:27,sep='')])`

You can still use `attach(a)` if you like (and if there's no element in '`a`' named '`a`'), but there is no need.